# Export JSON data to CSV file for Excel

Tags: javascript, csv

Given an array of data objects

```
const data = [{
    "id": "CT20",
    "type": "a11y-unknown",
    "urls": ["https://www.example.com/test/"]
 },
 {
    "id": "BC192",
    "type": "a11y-true",
    "urls": [
      "https://www.example.com/something/",
      "https://www.example.com/another-thing/"
    ]
 }
]
```

I'm trying to convert the objects to a CSV file that can be imported to Excel so that it shows as:

```
id     |     type    |    urls
CT20   | a11y-unknown| https://www.example.com/test/
```

I'm using the following to get the keys:
`const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);`

then map over the data like so:

```
const commaSeparatedString = [keys.join(","),data.map(row => keys.map(key => row[key]).join(",")).join("\n")].join("\n");
```

However, this returns the following:

```
'id,type,urls\nCT20,a11y-unknown,https://www.example.com/test/\nBC192,a11y-true,https://www.example.com/something/,https://www.example.com/another-thing/'
```

When imported to Excel as a CSV file, and delimited with `\`, it appears like this:
[image]

How can I correctly map the objects so that they are delimited and line break after each set of urls?

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "CT20",
    "type": "a11y-unknown",
    "urls": ["https://www.example.com/test/"]
 },
 {
    "id": "BC192",
    "type": "a11y-true",
    "urls": [
      "https://www.example.com/something/",
      "https://www.example.com/another-thing/"
    ]
 }
]

const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
const commaSeparatedString = [keys.join(","),data.map(row => keys.map(key => row[key]).join(",")).join("\n")].join("\n");
console.log(commaSeparatedString)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, the `csv` must be delimited with the same delimiter used when importing it, also for reliability all the fields should be included into quotes, so since in your case the delimiter is `\`, your attempt can be rewritten as below:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "CT20",
    "type": "a11y-unknown",
    "urls": ["https://www.example.com/test/"]
 },
 {
    "id": "BC192",
    "type": "a11y-true",
    "urls": [
      "https://www.example.com/something/",
      "https://www.example.com/another-thing/"
    ]
 }
]

const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
const commaSeparatedString = [keys.join("\\"),data.map(row => keys.map(key => `"${[row[key]].flat().join()}"`).join("\\")).join("\n")].join("\n");
console.log(commaSeparatedString)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have fixed number of columns. So either `JSON.stringify` the `urls` array, or designate columns such as `url1`, `url2`, `url3`...

EDIT: naturally if you don't escape commas by enclosing them in quotes, it will break the CSV. Genrally speaking you should use a library for parsing CSV such as [papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com/).

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "CT20",
    "type": "a11y-unknown",
    "urls": ["https://www.example.com/test/"]
  },
  {
    "id": "BC192",
    "type": "a11y-true",
    "urls": [
      "https://www.example.com/something/",
      "https://www.example.com/another-thing/"
    ]
  }
]

var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
var arr = [keys, ...data.map(row => keys.map(key => {
  return typeof row[key] === "string" ? row[key] : JSON.stringify(row[key])
}))];

// don't!
// .join(",")).join("\n")].join("\n");

// instead
var csv = Papa.unparse(arr);
console.log(csv)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```